# WPF - Add controls from button event

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I'm currently adding controls in the code behind then walking the visual tree to retrieve the values.

```
<StackPanel Name="StackPanel1/>

Dim _TextBox As New TextBox()
StackPanel1.children.insert(index, _TextBox)
```

There is a button click event that adds an additional textbox to the stackpanel by the user.

I'm thinking an itemscontrol would be more eloquent and would fit with the MVVM pattern better.  I'm not sure of the best way to set this up allowing the user to delete a textbox at any given index in the panel.  Wouldn't you still need to walk the tree to get the appropriate index for the control they opted to delete?  Currently as the controls are added a delete button is added next to the control.  I can then walk the tree and get the index.

Comment: You should be able to remove by reference. I don't think an index is necessary. Something such as ItemsSource.Remove(_TextBox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a `DataTemplate` on an `ItemsControl` (like you said), the `DataTemplate` could have the remove button attached to remove itself from the `ItemsControl`.
This is only a quick example and you should implement `CommandBindings` instead of the event handlers I added

The example code is in c# but its pretty simple and I'm sure you can convert it pretty easy

Xaml:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400" Name="UI" >

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox x:Name="txtbx" Text="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="175"  />
                <Button Content="X" Width="{Binding ElementName=txtbx, Path=ActualHeight}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}" Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=Models}" Margin="0,40,0,0" />
        <Button Content="Add" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,8,0,0" Name="Button_Add" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Add_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyModel> _models = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Models
    {
        get { return _models; }
        set { _models = value; }
    }

    private void Button_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Models.Add(new MyModel());
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Models.Remove((sender as Button).Tag as MyModel);
    }
}

public  class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _value;

    public string Value 
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Value"); } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```